# Does a high-listed attribute in a Decision Tree represent a major cause for the target class?

Tags: decision-theory

I am wondering about two questions:
Let us assume we have a Decision Tree, which wants to predict health. If the attribute "smoking (yes/no/occasionally)" is listed relatively high in the tree, does that mean it is a major cause for health?
And are attributes which are not included in the Decision Tree not a relevant cause for health?
I would affirm both statements but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "No".  Trees pick up on correlations, and we all know [correlation does not mean causation](https://www.tylervigen.com/spurious-correlations).  Classic example:  I could use ice cream sales to predict shark attacks.  There is clearly no causal link, but the two do share a common cause, namely temperature (hot temperatures mean ice cream sales may increase and more people go swimming hence at risk for shark attack.

Additionally, variables not split on may be related to the outcome, but the effect too small hence the tree decides to split on other characteristics strongly related to the outcome.